# How to reduce the frequency of CPU?

Tags: windows, cpu, cpufreq

I want to reduce the frequency of the CPU because it is always at full frequency also when I do nothing and I stay only on the desktop.
On the CPU appear core speed 4200GHz, the frequency is set on AUTO.
I didn't do overclock and I have Windows 10. What should I do?

Comment: And where exactly did you set the frequency to “Auto”? Look into Control Panel → Power Options – what profile is your system set to?

Comment: The frequency is high set on Auto 38. @Daniel B

Comment: Like @DanielB said, check the power plan and try setting it to balanced or Power Saver. Also, some very old processors don't support lowering frequency AFAIK, so which processor is this?

Comment: All the informations are  z270auros gaming 5 GB with bios f5 , CPU i5 7600k , trident Z rgb 3200GHz , 1070GB, power supply 600W

Comment: @user238173 - Update your question.

Comment: set power plan to balanced in power settings